# Displaying data from JDBC select statement

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, resultset

I am creating a program that is going to allow for displaying and manipulating data from my database. I wrote the following code based on a tutorial I found:

```
public class JavaApplication25 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:*****";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "****", "****");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Patients");

            System.out.println(rs);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of the code:

```
run:
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet@1cda59b
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

My question is why doesn't the program show me the data that is in my SQL Server database? Can anyone tell me how to display it?

I re-code it to this :

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JavaApplication25 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:OJT_dsn";
        String user = "sa";
        String pass = "";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT pIDNo,pLName,pFName,pMI,pSex,pStatus FROM dbo.Patients";
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(result.next()){
            int ID = result.getInt("ID");
            String Lname = result.getString("Lname");
            String Fname = result.getString("Fname");
            String MI = result.getString("MI");
            String Sex = result.getString("Sex");
            String Status = result.getString("Status");

            System.out.println(ID);
            System.out.println(Lname);
            System.out.println(Fname);
            System.out.println(MI);
            System.out.println(Sex);
            System.out.println(Status);
        }
        result.close();
        statement.close(); 

}catch(Exception ex){

  ex.printStackTrace();

}

}
}
```

what is wrong to my codings? Now I got this error :

java.sql.SQLException: Column not found
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.findColumn(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:1849)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:600)
    at javaapplication25.JavaApplication25.main(JavaApplication25.java:28)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Take a look at the [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) api. Also look at how `System.out.println()` deals with `toString()`.

Comment: Your program is doing exactly what you asked it to do, aka print out the `ResultSet` object. Thats what the `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet@1cda59b` is.

Comment: There is NO NEED TO SHOUT. We're all able to read, and SHOUTING won't get you answers any sooner. (It's also quite rude.)

Comment: sorry for shout, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are displaying the `Object#toString` representation of your `ResultSet`. You need to navigate through it instead.

```
while (rs.next()) {
      String name = rs.getString("name");
      System.out.println(name);
      // display more fields, etc.
      ...
}
```

Also consider using a `PreparedStatement` to guard against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: sir Reimeus how can I apply that rs.next() thing? quite newbie in JAVA thing

Comment: Would recommend that you read the docs first. Also here's a [good tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/index.html)

Comment: sir Reimeus see my question I add something on it..

Comment: You need to match the values uses in `getString` with names of your columsn, e.g. `rs.getString("pFName")`

Comment: ok thanks! it works out so well! thanks for the link :) really appreciate it!

Comment: one more thing, If I'm going to insert data to my DB can I used the same process?

Comment: Not exactly. You would need to use `executeUpdate`. Again I'll point you to the tutorial.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27521/discussion-between-crystal-maiden-and-reimeus)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 System.out.println(rs.getString("DATA"));
```

`System.out.println(rs);` just prints the `ResultSet` object. You need to get the column using [ResultSet#getString(String columnLabel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) method to get the column details. Don't forget to use [rs.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) method to navigate your result set.

***Edit:***
For your case

```
while (rs.next()) {
      // Read the values
      int pIDno = rs.getInt("pIDno");
      String pFName = rs.getString("pFName");
      String pLName = rs.getString("pLName");

      // Print the values
      System.out.println(name);
      System.out.println(pFName);
      System.out.println(pLName);   
}
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found

Comment: What is your column name in the database. Use that name in the getName method.

Comment: I have a lots of column like pIDno(integer), pFName(String), pLName(String), so on and so forth.... actually my DB is a patient list

Comment: Find the edited reply.

Comment: sir Jayamohan I edited my question kindly look at it.